# Cups showing remote jobs as completed, not printing

Tags: fedora, raspbian, cups

I've got an Epson Stylus DX3800 printer connected to a Raspberry Pi running raspbian (jessie).  The printer is configured in cups and I can print local jobs without problems.

Cups is configured to share that printer and the printer is detected and configured as a remote printer on my laptop running Fedora.  Anything I print from that laptop is accepted by the RasPi and the job shows up as completed immediately in the cups web interface (on both machines), but the printer won't budge at all.

When I connect the printer directly to the laptop and configure it locally, it prints just fine.  Interestingly, the network printer does print (albeit badly) when I use a generic postscript printer driver on the remote machine.

The latter fact leads me to believe it might be a driver issue: the RasPi is running the latest version of cups for jessie, which is 1.5.3, while Fedora already has 2.1.3.  Similarly, the driver I'm using on the laptop is identified as "Epson Stylus DX3800 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.**11** (color)" and that on the RasPi is "Epson Stylus DX3800 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.**10** (color, 2-sided printing)".

Comment: Upgrading to a more recent version of CUPS on the Pi should not be difficult. You can backport if necessary. But are you sure that's the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure, no. In fact I'd normally believe clients should not have to run exactly the same software and driver versions. But I really don't know what else could be the problem.

Comment: Ok. Well, try the same version of CUPS on both machines, then.